# Configure botfront and msteam (botframework)

Tags: botframework, rasa

I'm currently working on integrating Botfront and Microsoft Teams BotFramework in my project, and I'm having trouble configuring the credentials tab in Botfront. Specifically, I'm not sure how to properly set up the required credentials for my bot to work with Teams. My current code is displayed below

```
rasa_addons.core.channels.webchat.WebchatInput:
  session_persistence: true
  base_url: '<url>'
  socket_path: /socket.io/
rasa_addons.core.channels.bot_regression_test.BotRegressionTestInput: {}
rasa_addons.core.channels.botframework.BotFrameworkInput:
  app_id: app_id
  app_password: app_password
  base_url: '<url>'
```

Error occurs when starting botfront-rasa:

`rasa.shared.exceptions.RasaException: Failed to find input channel class for 'rasa_addons.core.channels.botframework.BotFrameworkInput'. Unknown input channel. Check your credentials configuration to make sure the mentioned channel is not misspelled. If you are creating your own channel, make sure it is a proper name of a class in a module.`

Can anyone share experience about it.

Thank you.